# How to read row height by using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Always, when I'm trying to read row height in EPPlus, sets default height

```
    private static void SetRowHeight (ExcelWorksheet worksheet, int startRow, int endRow)
    {
        var height = worksheet.Row(startRow).Height;
        for (int i = startRow; i <= endRow; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Row(i).Height = height;
        }
    }
```